# Setting up log4j2 with Scala project

Tags: scala, maven, log4j2

I am using `Maven` for my Scala project and I am trying to use log4j2.

At First, I just added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

To list of my dependency and add the following XML file to my resources folder. I have created the `resources` folder alongside scala folder both in `main` and `test`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{0} %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="com.simpleproject" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Yet it didn't work a produce this error :

> ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation.
>   Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to
>   the console...

Even I tried properties file instead of XML but still no luck:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/full-scala.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=guru.springframework.blog.log4j2properties
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Then I find this [post](https://github.com/tobciu/NotifyMyAndroidLib/issues/1), so I update my `pom.xml` to have this 3 dependancy:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api-scala_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

But Still I get the same error and it doesn't show the log the way I want or the level of the log I want (Only shows level above Error)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apache page](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/scala/dependency-management.html) of this project `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` versions should be 2.8.2 (Version 2.8.2 worked for this case)

According to [GitHub page](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j-scala/) of this project `log4j-api` and `log4j-core` versions should be 2.11.0

Comment: I just pasted Spark by mistake, it wasn't for this issue

Comment: 2.8.2 works but 2.9.1 didn't, what is the issue? why it's not working with the latest version?

Comment: @Am1rr3zA probablly api has ben changed, and their GitHub page has wrong info. 2.9.1 might work for version 13 of Scala-log4j